# Clickable link in active editor

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

If I add a link to the active editor either by using the menu/context menu or by simply typing a URL (e.g., http://www.google.com), the link is added but it is not immediately clickable.  The only way a user can use the link to navigate to a page is by ctrl-clicking and choosing to open in a new tab.  If the editor is in read-only mode then it works as intended but not when the editor is active.

Is there a way to make links clickable in an active editor?

thnx,
Christoph

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TinyMCE will not (by default) make the link clickable.  You can right click on the link and a context menu appears.  In that menu is an option to open the link.  To modify a link one needs to click on it (select it) in TinyMCE.  If that act (clicking) opened the link you would not be able to easily select the link to act upon it in the editor.